# push method to add elements into array not working while getting id and value of elements having same class

Tags: javascript

My intention is to get the id and value of all elements having same class which i'm able to but pushing the same into an array is not working for me.
Any help is appreciated.
below is my javascript function:

content1 is the class having multiple divs (cloned with first div) created on click of button.
but my array length is always zero.

```
var newList = [];

function Intfdata(){
var numItems = $('.content1').length;
alert(numItems);


       $.each($('.content1 *[id]'), function(index, value) {


var currentId=($(value).attr('id'));    
    var currentVal= (this.value);
 alert(currentId +" and " + currentVal  );



               newList.push = ({currentId, currentVal});   

                           });

  alert(newList.length);    


};
```

HTML is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.4.1/processing-api.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file:///C:/Users/sp0065506/Desktop/xml generation/RRICdatascript_MI.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>Router Interface data generation</title>

  <h1>Router Interface data generation</h1>


  </head>
  <body>

     <div id="gen_fields">

            <div class="content">
            <span>Customer: <input type="text" id="Customer" style="width:48px;" name="Customer[]" value="" /></span>
            <span>CountryCode: <input type="text" id="CountryCode" style="width:48px;" name="CountryCode[]" value="" /></span>
            <span>HostName: <input type="text" id="HostName" style="width:200px;" name="HostName[]" value="" /></span>
            <span>InterfaceName: <input type="text" id="InterfaceName" style="width:200px;" name="InterfaceName[]" value="" /></span>

            </div>
            <div>
            <span>ManagementIP: <input type="text" id="ManagementIP" style="width:100px;" name="ManagementIP[]" value="" /></span>
            <span>SubnetMask: <input type="text" id="SubnetMask" style="width:100px;" name="SubnetMask[]" value="" /></span>
                <span>IPMode: <select id="IPMode" name="IPMode[]" value="" /></span>
                <option value="0">IPv4</option>
                <option value="2">IPv6</option>
                <option value="1">Both</option>
                </select>

            </div>

      <button id="InterfaceButton"  name="InterfaceButton[]" value="" onclick="duplicate();">Add Interface</button> 
    <div class="content1" id="intffields" value="">

            <div class='label'>InterfaceList:</div>

                <span>Action: <select id="Action" name="Action[]" value="" /></span>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
                <option value="D">D</option>
                </select>
                <span>PortName: <input type="text" id="PortName" style="width:200px;" name="PortName[]" value="" /></span>
                <span>PortType: <input type="text" id="PortType" style="width:200px;" name="PortType[]" value="" /></span>
                <span>IPAddress: <input type="text" id="IPAddress" style="width:200px;" name="IPAddress[]" value="" /></span>
                <span>SubnetMask: <input type="text" id="SubnetMask1" style="width:200px;" name="SubnetMask1[]" value="" /></span>
                <div>
                <span>IPv6Address: <input type="text" id="IPV6Address" style="width:200px;" name="IPV6Address[]" value="" /></span>
                <span>IPv6Length: <input type="text" id="IPV6Length" style="width:50px;" name="IPV6Length[]" value="" /></span>
                <span>PortLevelInterface:<select id="PortLevelInterface" name="PortLevelInterface[]" value="">/span>
                <option value=" "></option>
                <option value="Y">Y</option>
                <option value="N">N</option>
                </select>
                <span>PortLevelCos:<select id="PortLevelCos" name="PortLevelCos[]" value="">/span>
                <option value=" "></option>
                <option value="Y">Y</option>
                <option value="N">N</option>
                </select>
                <span>PortSpeed: <input type="text" id="PortSpeed" style="width:50px;" name="PortSpeed[]" value="" /></span>
                <span>CosMode: <select id="CosMode" name="CosMode[]" value="">/span>
                <option value="Reset Mode">None Mode</option>
                <option value="Transparent Mode">Transparent Mode</option>
                <option value="Passive Mode">Passive Mode</option> 
                <option value="Provider Mode">Provider Mode</option>
                <option value="None Mode">Reset Mode</option>
                </select>
                <span>LCType: <input type="text" id="LCType" style="width:50px;" name="LCType[]" value="" /></span>
                <span>Usage: <select id="Usage" name="Usage[]" value="">/span>
                <option value="Network Access">Network Access</option>
                <option value="Cascaded Access">Cascaded Access</option>
                <option value="Customer Access">Customer Access</option> 
                <option value="Resiliency Access">Resiliency Access</option>
                <option value="Backup Network Access">Backup Network Access</option>
                </select>
                <span>TCGroup_No: <input type="text" id="TCGroup_No" style="width:50px;" name="TCGroup_No[]" value="" /></span>
                <span>COSModel:<select id="COSModel" class="cosm" name="COSModel" value="" onchange="divclick(this);"></span>
                <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="4COS">4COS</option>
                <option value="6COS">6COS</option>
                </select>
                </div>


                <div id="holder"></div>
                <div class="content2">
                </div>

                <div id="4COS"  class="style-sub-1"  style="display: none;" name="stylesub1" >
    <label for="CatchAllClass">CatchAllClass:</label>


<select name="cat" id="cat" class="postform">

<option class="level-0" value="COS1">COS1</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS2">COS2</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS3">COS3</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS4">COS4</option>
</select>
    <label for="FragmentClass">FragmentClass:</label>
    <select name="cat1" id="cat1" class="postform">

<option class="level-0" value="COS1">COS1</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS2">COS2</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS3">COS3</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS4">COS4</option>
</select>
</div>
    <div id="6COS"  class="style-sub-1"  style="display: none ;" name="stylesub1" >
    <label for="CatchAllClass">CatchAllClass:</label>
    <select name="cat" id="cat" class="postform">

<option class="level-0" value="COS1">COS1</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS2">COS2</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS2V">COS2V</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS3">COS3</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS4">COS4</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS5">COS5</option>
</select>
    <label for="FragmentClass">FragmentClass:</label>

<select name="cat1" id="cat1" class="postform">

<option class="level-0" value="COS1">COS1</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS2">COS2</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS2V">COS2V</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS3">COS3</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS4">COS4</option>
<option class="level-0" value="COS5">COS5</option>
</select>
</div>
</div> 

</div>              


<div id="download"> 
    <button id="DownloadButton">Create file</button>
 <div>   
    <div id="generated" style="display:none">
      <h2>RouterInterfaceData.xml</h2>

      <textarea id="ResultXml" style="width: 100%; height: 100em" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand how `push` works and also how an object is structured.

You are trying to push an object into an array. The object should look like:

```
{ currentId: currentId, currentVal: currentVal }
```

where you have a number of key/value pairs.

`push` should be used like this:

```
newList.push({ currentId: currentId, currentVal: currentVal });
```